# Divergence of a double sum

Tags: sequences-and-series

I wanted to prove the divergence of the following sum $ \sum\limits _{n=2}^\infty((-1)^n\sin(b\log(n))g(n)$. I expanded the sine function and rearranged the terms to get $\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^i b^{2i}}{(2i-1)!}\sum\limits _{n=2}^\infty((-1)^n(\log(n))^i g(n)$. What can be possible functions $g(n)$ for the above sum to diverge?

Comment: Expanding the sine is a deadend. The question is probably designed to make you apply Abel's lemma.